# How to save_fig a matplotlib subplot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have *n* figures with 4 subplots each. The thing is that each subplot has its own settings and I tried turning each of them into a figure to no avail.

So the question still stands: How can I save_fig each individual subplot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just create 4 figures and then save them using `savefig`?

Comment: Saving each individual subplot is other way of saying saving each plot. Just create 4 figures

Comment: There are plenty of such Q&A out there and the solution is always the same: Create a function which takes an axes as argument and then either create a figure with one axes and call one of the functions with that figure's axes as argument or create a figure with 4 subplots and call all functions with those 4 subplots as argument - depending on whether you then want a single figure or 4 figures.